# ng-click doesn't affect parent's children

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Why does this not really work?

I have a field test.

But when I click on the `<p>` of child1 it will not affect the child2 `<p>`.

```
<div ng-init="test=false">
    <div id="child1">
        <p ng-click="test=!test">
            Click!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
        <p ng-if="test">
            Clicked..
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because `ngIf` creates a separate child scope. And when you declare variables inline variables - you create them on the scope of that html element. So anything inside the `ngIf` is on that scope

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an angular module in JS and assign it using the ng-app directive.  Like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sample">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('sample', []);
  </script>
</head>


<body>
  <div ng-init="test=false">
    <div id="child1">
      <p ng-click="test=!test">
        Click!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
      <p ng-if="test">
        Clicked..
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Every directive creates its own scope.

So,if you want to access the variable/object in parent scope, you need use `$parent`

```
<div ng-init="test=false">
    <div id="child1">
        <p ng-click="$parent.test=!$parent.test">
            Click!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
        <p ng-if="$parent.test">
            Clicked..
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```